# PHP Angularjs JSON multiple API Responses

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm using a movie api(https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api), the api only gives me 20 results per page, i want to get 60, so i make 3 requests for 3 pages.
I dont know if i have to use json encode or decode the response but this works for the first result list:

```
$url1 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=1&language=de";
    $url2 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=2&language=de";
        $url3 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=3&language=de";

$response1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$response2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$response3 = file_get_contents($url3);

echo $response1;
```

I dont know how to put the results of the second and third request into 'results':

[image]

angular part

```
a.filme = []; //declare an empty array

            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'data/call-api.php'
            }).then(function (response){
                a.filme = response.data.results;
                console.log(response.data);
            },function (error){
                console.log("JSON konnte nicht geladen werden: " + error.status + error.statusText);
            });
```

the reponse in the browser of the api (http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=1&language=de) looks like this: 
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only need the results.

```
$url1 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=1&language=de";
$url2 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=2&language=de";
$url3 = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=###&page=3&language=de";

//extract results from each response and merge to single array
$response1 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1),true)["results"];
$response2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2),true)["results"];
$response3 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url3),true)["results"];

echo json_encode(array_merge($response1,$response2,$response3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only after the results list you can use:

```
$apiKey = "###";

$out = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=".$apiKey."&page=".$i."&language=de";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);

    if (is_array($response->results)) {
        $out = array_merge($out, $response->results);
    }
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

In angular just use `console.log(response);`